# How to send file upload path with normal data to controller in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I want to send File upload image path with normal data to controller in jquery by ajax call . When i send only normal data then it works properly. When i send only image path then it also works but when i send both in one time then it doesn't work. It creates a issue like sometime ajax call doesn't work or sometime value shows null in controller.

I found many things on net but could not find the exact solution. I found some solutions like.... missing " enctype" & way to getting file upload path & many others.

This is my JS file coding. It is working properly and am getting complete image path in controller.

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $("#btnUploadFile").get(0).files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    data.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]);
}
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Login/submitUserProfile',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});

    Controller

[HttpPost]
public void submitUserProfile()
{
    Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"]; 
    //getting image path properly
}
```

Simple view - 
Just use @using(Html.BeginForm.......enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
and controls

But i want to send one extra parameter with image path...

```
    var userDetail = {};
    userDetail.experience = experience;
    userDetail.priceType = priceType;
    userDetail.services = services;
```

Now, I want controller should be get image path as well as userDetail information that i specified above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got solution of this question. Now, I can send image path with normal data to controller in jquery.

JS Coding

```
    var userProfile = {};
    var userDetail = {};

    var hidUserId = $('#hidUserId').val();
    var userName = $('#txtUserName').val();

    var experience = $('#txtExperience').val();
    var priceType = $('#txtPriceType').val();

    userProfile.hidUserId = hidUserId;
    userProfile.userName = userName;

    userDetail.experience = experience;
    userDetail.priceType = priceType;

    var UserProfileJson = JSON.stringify(userProfile);
    var UserDetailJson = JSON.stringify(userDetail);

    var data = new FormData();
    var files = $("#btnUploadFile").get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("userUploadedImage", files[0]);
        data.append("userProfileJson", UserProfileJson);
        data.append("userDetailJson", UserDetailJson);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Login/submitUserProfile',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string submitUserProfile()
    {
        try
        {
            string userProfileJson = Request.Form["userProfileJson"];
            string userDetailJson = Request.Form["userDetailJson"];
            HttpPostedFileBase userImage = Request.Files["userUploadedImage"];
         }
    }
```